# Open Application when receive Call even if an application in background

Tags: android

I'm developing an application for calling and receiving the SIP call.
I receive the SIP call in my application when it is open,But not receive the call when an application in background.

This is my service class with broadcast receiver that notify incoming call and start an `Activity` for take call:

```
public class ReceiveCallService extends Service {

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

// use this as an inner class like here or as a top-level class
public static class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public SipAudioCall incomingCall;
    public static MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent();

        i.setClassName("com.myapp",
                "com.myapp.SipCallReceiveActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        mPlayer = MediaPlayer
                .create(MyAppContext.getContext(), R.raw.sugar);
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mPlayer.start();

        try {

            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
                    try {
                        call.answerCall(30);
                        Constant.incomingCall.startAudio();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallHeld(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCallHeld(call);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCallEstablished(call);

                    Log.e("call Is Established", "Yes!!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallBusy(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCallBusy(call);
                    AppSettings.setSp_iscallEnded(
                            MyAppContext.getContext(), true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        call.endCall();
                        Log.e("call Is Ended Service...", "Yes!!");
                        AppSettings.setSp_iscallEnded(
                                MyAppContext.getContext(), true);
                        mPlayer.stop();
                    } catch (SipException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    super.onCallEnded(call);

                }

            };
            incomingCall = Constant.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);



            if (AppSettings.getSp_isOutGoingcallRunning(MyAppContext
                    .getContext()) == false
                    && AppSettings.getSp_isInComingcallRunning(MyAppContext
                            .getContext()) == false) {
                Constant.incomingCall = incomingCall;
                Constant.updateStatus(incomingCall);
                context.startActivity(i);
                AppSettings.SetSp_IsIncomingCall(MyAppContext.getContext(),
                        true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (incomingCall != null) {
                incomingCall.close();
            }
            if (Constant.me != null) {
                try {
                    Constant.manager.close(Constant.me.getUriString());
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                            "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                    ee.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    // constructor
    public MyReceiver() {

    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // get an instance of the receiver in your service
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
    mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    MyReceiver.mPlayer.stop();
}
}
```

Now i want to receive the call in an application even it is on background.

Answer (score 0):

Register a broadcast receiver in android manifest like:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.something.CallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And get the incoming call event in you BroadcastReciever Class like this.

in OnReceive() method

```
String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
if ((state != null) && (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) {
```

use it.

enjoy happy coding :)